# Find most common object in a list in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, data-analysis

I am having difficulty in printing out the most popular web link and then counting the amount of times it appears. Instead, all links are printed out and none are counted. I'm not sure if I am misplacing my `Counter` and `.most_common(1)` in my code. I have pasted it below.

```
toplinks = []

for i in itb:
if "://" in i[1].lower() and '2015-11-16' in i[2].lower():
    itb_links = [c for c in i[1].split(" ") if "://" in c.lower()]
    ##toplinks = collections.Counter(itb_links).most_common(1)
    toplinks.append(itb_links)
    for i in toplinks:
        print ("Top web link: " , i[0] , i[1] )
```

I commented out my `toplinks` in the for loop because it seems to do nothing, but duplicate the web link. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is `itb`? Can you provide some sample input/outputs?

Comment: A naive solution would be to iterate through the list and, for each iteration, increment a counter for the corresponding entry in a second list of unique entries. At the end, just return the entry in the second list with the highest count.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your `itb` object to reconstruct, so here's a trivial example that shows how to initialise a `Counter` from a list.

```
import collections
import random

#generate some random links
links = ["http://go{}.invalid".format(random.randint(1, 20)) for _ in range(1000)]
link_counter = collections.Counter(links)
print(link_counter.most_common(3))
```

Which will print something like:

```
[('http://go2.invalid', 59), ('http://go5.invalid', 59), ('http://go12.invalid', 57)]
```

See the [docs on collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for more information.